# Export Report as Record Style in C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I need to Export a report as a RecordStyle columns without spaces in C#.Net
I'm not sure what .dll I need to add in.  currently in the CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll there is an ExportFormatType Enum but it does not contain an option for RecordStyle.
I have seen places where you can use Constants crEFTRecordStyle but not sure where that comes from.  any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work.

Posting Answer here in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

Needed to Add CRAXDRT.dll as a reference to my project.

CRAXDRT.Report report = new Report();
CRAXDRT.Application app = new Application();
report = app.OpenReport("ReportName.rpt", OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByDefault);

report.ExportOptions.DestinationType = CRExportDestinationType.crEDTDiskFile;
report.ExportOptions.DiskFileName = "C:\SaveReportAs.txt";
report.ExportOptions.FormatType = CRExportFormatType.crEFTRecordStyle;
report.Export(false);